# Setting a fe_users session from extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

As I have to verify the login-data in a way, normal login extensions can not handle, I have to develop a custom login-form. This login box is part of an ext. written in extbase.

But I stuck with a basic question: How can i handle fe_users sessions in extbase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it, by combining lots of snippets. Thats how it worked out for me:

```
$loginData = array(
  'uname' => $loginData['user'],
  'uident' => $loginData['passw'],
  'status' => 'login'
);

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
$info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
$user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord( $info['db_user'], $loginData['uname'] );
if ( $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->compareUident($user,$loginData) )
{
    $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData(); 
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->start();
    $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
    $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->loginSessionStarted = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Did you note that your line with the if clause ends in a semicolon?(!!!) Your snippet pretty much lets anyone with any password log in because: if(false);{ echo'hello'; } I hope anyone using this snippet has checked the fail state.

Comment: I reemphasize on the comment I left on this answer more than half a year ago: this code is broken! It lets any correct username log in with any password! Remove this crap so no one ever uses it!

Comment: I removed the semicolon, so you won't have to re-reemphasize. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In fact, it now wont work in any case, because the identification always failed, and you just ignored the false return that compareUident handed you.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this [function](https://github.com/websafari/ws_login/blob/master/Classes/Service/LoginService.php), maybe it helps:

```
/** @var $fe_user tslib_feUserAuth */
$fe_user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user;
$fe_user->createUserSession(array('uid' => $uid));
$fe_user->user = $fe_user->getRawUserByUid($uid);
$fe_user->fetchGroupData();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
```

It's inspired by [Tx_Phpunit_Framework::loginFrontEndUser($userId)](http://www.autohaus-daub.de/typo3conf/ext/phpunit/doc/Framework/class_tx___phpunit___framework.html#aae3a03a032b321f13e3ac3aa04c8d59e) :

```
// Instead of passing the actual user data to createUserSession, we
// pass an empty array to improve performance (e.g. no session record
// will be written to the database).
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession(array());
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getRawUserByUid($userId);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers provided seemed to work for me in TYPO3 6.2. The fix is described in a Bugreport in the Forge, https://forge.typo3.org/issues/62194 . Basically, the SessionCookie isn't placed automatically anymore, you need to do that on your own now, adding

```
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
        $setSessionCookieMethod = $reflection->getMethod('setSessionCookie');
        $setSessionCookieMethod->setAccessible(TRUE);
        $setSessionCookieMethod->invoke($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
```

after calling the createUserSession().