# TYPO3 6.1 - how can I login a fe_user via code?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am using TYPO3 6.1 and try to login a FE user via Code (included via PHP and USER_INT).

This code does not work for me. :( Any ideas why?

```
// try to login the user now
$loginData = array(
    'uname'   => trim($postData['username']), //usernmae
    'uident'  => trim($postData['password']), //password
    'status'  => 'login'
);

// $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user-checkPid=0; //do not use a particular pid
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = $this->feUserPid; // ''; //do not use a particular pid
$info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();

// 
$user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord(
    $info['db_user'], $loginData['uname']
);

$ok = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->compareUident($user, $loginData);

//
if($ok) 
{        
    // login successfull
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);

    // 
    $content = '<h3 class="green">LOGIN OK!</h3>';
    $content .= '<p>Sie sind eingeloggt als ' . $feUsername . ' und wurden nun weitergeleitet...</p>';
} 
else 
{
    // login failed
    $content = '<h3 class="red">LOGIN FAILED!</h3>'; 
}
```

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with TYPO3 4.7, you must use $loginData['uident_text'] instead of $loginData['uident'] for the password.

If the problem persists, please give more information what exactly is going wrong, what your log says etc.

Comment: Hi lorenz, when I use ['uident'], an entry is created in the fe_sessions table, but $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['username'] stays empty in my debug output. When using ['uident_text'], no entry in the fe_sessions table is created. Thanks for help

Comment: Anyone else an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Does compareUident() return TRUE for you?
I, fx have a case, where I automatically log in user that has just created themselves. And compareUident() didn't work for me for some reason, but as I know this same website visitor just created the user, I skip that function and continue on initiating all the session variables. The following is a working code on TYPO3 6.1:

```
$loginData = array(
    'uname' => $postdata['username'],
    'uident' => $postdata['password'],
    'status' => 'login',
);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
$info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
$user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $loginData['uname']);
//if($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->compareUident($user, $loginData)) {
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData(); 
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->start();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->loginSessionStarted = TRUE;
//}
```

Inspired by:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738383/445364

https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dix_easylogin